# How to set Excel date with text in a single cell with dateformats

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

I have an excel report which is generated from the web application.

In that report I need to place  "`(01/25/2013)` Control", it's getting from a database query. I can't change the database query.

I want to change the date format as `dd/mm/yyyy` with including text like "`(25/01/2013)` Control", but my query gives date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Please help me regarding above one.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to format the cell in the following way

Custom Number Format

"("dd/mm/yyyy") Control"